Set default value depending on language of record in Backend form
I would like to set a language specific default value for a custom field (input or RTE field) in TYPO3 Backend, so something like setting $GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_myrecords_domain_model_record']['columns']['disclaimer']['config']['default'], but giving it a different value, depending on the language of the record (sys_language_uid).
e.g. default value of "disclaimer" would be "Please consider our ..." if the record is the default language and "Bitte beachten Sie unsere ..." in the translated record (German).

AFAIK,

I can set the default value with TCAdefaults.tx_myrecords_domain_model_record.disclaimer (but it would always be the same, not language dependant). This is also works with RTE fields and using HTML in the default text.
it is not possible to set a dynamic default value in TCA
it is for example possible to set the label language-specific. This is  not what I want (this sets the "label", not the "default" and depends on the language of the BE user, not the language of the record).

TSconfig:
TCEFORM.pages.title {
    label = LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:table.column
    label.default = New Label
    label.de = Neuer Feldname
}

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/main/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html#tceform_label-example

for TYPO3 version >= v12.

I think you will need to implement a custom input field to achive that.
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/12.4/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/User/Index.html

Is passing the ID/reference of the translated text not possible? It's just as thought, not approved...

@Julian You mean something like TCAdefaults.tx_myrecords_domain_model_record.disclaimer = LLL:EXT:... ? I tried that, but then this is used as text. Also, I suspect, if it worked, it would use the current language of the BE user and not the language of the record.

Yes, meant something like that. But I thought more of FE usage... So passing the value to the template and insert/handle it via f:translate than... For BE use is such a way hard/impossible/hacky.

Alright, you have to use PHP then.
First, register a hook inside one the ext_localconf.php file of your provider extension or site package (assuming you have one), specify the correct PHP namespace:
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass'][] = \Vendor\Extension\Hooks\DataHandlerHook::class;

Second, add a hook class with the following code and adapt it to your language ids:
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Hooks;

class DataHandlerHook
{
    public function processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray($status, $table, $id, &$fieldArray, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler $pObj)
    {
        // Only target the tx_news_domain_model_news table
        if ($table === 'tx_news_domain_model_news') {
            // Check if the 'title' field is being updated
            if (empty($fieldArray['title'])) {
                // Language 0: Default value for default language
                if ($fieldArray['sys_language_uid'] == 0) {
                    $fieldArray['title'] = 'Default Title for Language 0';
                }
                // Language 1: Default value for language 1
                elseif ($fieldArray['sys_language_uid'] == 1) {
                    $fieldArray['title'] = 'Default Title for Language 1';
                }
                // Language 2: Default value for language 2
                elseif ($fieldArray['sys_language_uid'] == 2) {
                    $fieldArray['title'] = 'Default Title for Language 2';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Third, empty your caches.

This did not work for me so I tried it for news as well. Can you get this working with EXT:news?  TCEFORM.tx_news_domain_model_news.title.types.0.default.0 = default value in default lang
